# Conversion error from string from change to table column and one line in query

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table with multiple columns. The relevant columns are:

1. A `NUMERIC` column called `Hours`
2. A `BOOLEAN` column called `Active`
3. A `VARCHAR` column column called `Type`

`Type` used to also be `BOOLEAN` until I needed more than two possible values, so I changed the column to `VARCHAR`

I have a large query that used to work. Below is the part of the query I modified:

```sql
(
    SELECT SUM("Hours")
    FROM "Table"
    WHERE
        (
            "Type" = "B"
            AND "Active" = TRUE
        )
) AS "Label",
```

The only change in the above query section being from `"Type" = TRUE` to `"Type" = "B"`. No other line was changed. Now when I run the query, I receive the following error:

> Conversion error from string "A"

If I change that same line to `"Type" = "A"`, or `"Type" = "C"`, the error changes to:

```
*column unknown
*A
```

Or:

```
*column unknown
*C
```

My goal is to sum up `Hours` in `Table`, where the rows are `TRUE` for `Active` and of the specified `Type`. I'm not sure why an otherwise (seemingly) simple query fails.

Comment: Remove double-quote from values. "Type" = "B" should be "Type" = 'B'.

Comment: Also you don't have to put double quote. But if you want to have tables with names as TABLE, DATE or similar, you can do so if you put double quotas aroung strange name.

Comment: Rookie mistake, it seems! That cleared it right up! And yeah, not actually using those as names. Just scrubbed any identifying information for the question

Comment: @ValMarinov In the case of `Type` and `Active`, using double quotes is actually needed as those are reserved words (and because the table and column names seem to have been defined case-sensitively).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know. That's exactly what I was trying to say with my second comment. Sorry if not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that in the condition `"Type" = TRUE`, Firebird will coerce the values of column `Type` to a Boolean instead of converting `TRUE` to a string. This fails for values that are not `'TRUE'` or `'FALSE'` (case-insensitive). You need to use `= 'TRUE'` instead of `= TRUE`.

As to the second problem, double quotes in standard SQL and Firebird (at least in dialect 3, Firebird's default dialect) delimit identifiers, not strings. You need to use `'A'` and `'C'`, not `"A"` or `"C"` for strings. When you use `"A"`, Firebird sees it as a column reference to a column `A`, which in this case doesn't exist.

Comment: "Active" is declared as boolean in this case. What is the problem to use "Active" = TRUE?

Comment: @ValMarinov I mixed up `Active` and `Type`.